Scale z-normalized data back to original data range (using clustering of time series)
I am a little bit confused about the information from tslearn package for Python.
It says in the documentation (e.g. https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/clustering/plot_kmeans.html) that:

In this example, time series are preprocessed using TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance. This scaler is such that each output time series has zero mean and unit variance. The assumption here is that the range of a given time series is uninformative and one only wants to compare shapes in an amplitude-invariant manner (when time series are multivariate, this also rescales all modalities such that there will not be a single modality responsible for a large part of the variance). This means that one cannot scale barycenters back to data range because each time series is scaled independently and there is hence no such thing as an overall data range.

But if I find that, e.g., a cluster's assigned time series initially have a very similar mean value and standard deviation (or that the mean and standard deviation follow a function in this group, i.e., they are different but are connected to some metadata such as the size of the activity that the data come from), then isn't it very possible to re-scale the data?
Or am I missing something?
To rescale z-normalization, take the data points times the standard deviation and add the mean value. The same is true for other types of normalization, where every input is scaled independently; otherwise, the normalization would not make a difference and would only shift the data.
I do not mean that you can always get an estimation of the mean or the standard deviation that is meaningful, but the statement that it is not possible (at all) is making me confused.

Using knowledge of the original time series' means and variances, you can of course re-scale the data, just treating each time series separately. I don't think that this is what the cited text means, but it is awkwardly worded, so I'm not quite sure what exactly it refers to. What you propose would not provide an exact re-scaling, only an approximation (which wouldn't normally be called "re-scaling"), and not necessarily a good one.
